# Is there an easy way to check whether or not $3$ divides a number that is written in decimal notation?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

(*Convention.* I include $0$ in the natural numbers, i.e. $0 \in \mathbb{N}$)

> **Definition.** Whenever $n$ is a natural number, define that $$\langle n\rangle : \{0,\ldots,9\}^\mathbb{N}$$ is the unique such sequence satisfying $$n = \sum_{k:\mathbb{N}} \langle n \rangle_k 10^k.$$

For example, if $n = 475$, then $$\langle n \rangle = (\ldots,0,0,0,4,7,5),$$ where I've written the sequence backward for clarity.

Now given $n \in \mathbb{N}$, its easy to find the truthvalue of $2 \mid n$ and $5 \mid n$ just from looking at the sequence $\langle n\rangle$. In particular:

$$(2 \mid n) \iff \langle n \rangle_0 \in \{0,2,4,6,8\}$$

$$(5 \mid n) \iff \langle n \rangle_0 \in \{0,5\}$$

> **Question.** Suppose we're interested in the boolean $3 \mid n$. Is there a similar such "trick" for deciding its value in terms of the sequence $\langle n \rangle$?

Comment: $3 \mid n$ if the sum of the $n_k$ is a multiple of $3$ ?

Comment: @Watson, is that really true? **Edit.** Oh I see. Modular arithmetic. $10^n$ is always equal to $1$, if we're working modulo $3$.

Comment: [Yes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule#Divisibility_by_3_or_9)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For 3 (and 9) you have the useful fact that
$$ 10 \equiv 1 \pmod 3, $$
so $10^k \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ because $10*10*..*10 \equiv 1*1*..*1 \pmod 3$, and hence,
$$ n= \sum_k \langle n \rangle_k 10^k \equiv \sum_k \langle n \rangle_k \pmod 3, $$
which immediately gives you that $$n \equiv 0 \pmod 3 \iff \sum_k \langle n \rangle_k \equiv 0 \pmod 3$$.

Answer (score 4):

A number is divisible by $3$ if and only the sum of its digits is divisible by $3$.

Indeed :

$$n = \sum_{k:\mathbb{N}} \langle n \rangle_k 10^k \equiv 0\pmod 3 \iff \sum_{k:\mathbb{N}} \langle n \rangle_k \equiv 0\pmod 3 $$
since $10 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$.

A similar argument works for $9$ instead of $3$.